# PHP Regex HTML - Extract URL

Tags: php, html, regex

I am trying to extract multiple URLs from HTML file with regex.
There are other URLs in the file, do the only pattern i have is "tableentries." and ""

HTML code example:

```
<tr class="tableentries2">
  <td>
    <a href="http://example.com/all-files/files/00000000789/">Click Here</a>
  </td>
```

PHP I wrote:

```
$html = "value of the code above"
if(preg_match_all('/<td>.*</td>/', $html, $match)){
foreach($match[0] as $x){

echo $x . "<br>";

}}
```

Comment: What is your question exactly? what does this code get you? why does it not work?

Comment: Quotes are missing around your HTML attributes. `<tr class="tableentries2"> ... <a href="http://example.com/...">` (edited your question)

Comment: Maybe be use an DOM parser like http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 11):

Why not just look for `href` values? (Updated because the edited code now has quotation marks.)

```
preg_match_all('/href="([^\s"]+)/', $html, $match);
```

Then the URI would be in `$match[1][0]`.

Comment: Problem is there are also other URLs on the page, so the only pattern I have is "tableentries." and the beginning and "</a>" after the URL.Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 5):

You really shouldn't use regex to parse HTML. DOMDocument is actually very easy to use for this type of thing. here is a simple example.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$html = "
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href='http://www.test1-1.com'>test1-1</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href='http://www.test1-2.com'>test1-2</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href='http://www.test1-3.com'>test1-3</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href='http://www.test2-1.com'>test2-1</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href='http://www.test2-2.com'>test2-2</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href='http://www.test2-3.com'>test2-3</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>";

$DOM = new DOMDocument();
//load the html string into the DOMDocument
$DOM->loadHTML($html);
//get a list of all <A> tags
$a = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('a');
//loop through all <A> tags
foreach($a as $link){
    //echo out the href attribute of the <A> tag.
    echo $link->getAttribute('href').'<br />';
}
?>
```

This would output:

```
http://www.test1-1.com
http://www.test1-2.com
http://www.test1-3.com
http://www.test2-1.com
http://www.test2-2.com
http://www.test2-3.com
```

Comment: Problem is there are also other URLs on the page, so the only pattern I have is "tableentries." and the beginning and "</a>" after the URL.Thanks for helping!

Comment: how do you also grab the test1-2 titles of the link as well?

Comment: @thevoipman there is a nodeValue property you can use. something like `$link->nodeValue`. here is an example: http://codepad.viper-7.com/JBsfP1

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
preg_match_All("#<a\s[^>]*href\s*=\s*[\'\"]??\s*?(?'path'[^\'\"\s]+?)[\'\"\s]{1}[^>]*>(?'name'[^>]*)<#simU", $html, $hrefs, PREG_SET_ORDER);

foreach ($hrefs AS $urls){
 print $urls['path']."<br>";
}
?>
```