# Use PHP to find text within an HTML Page

Tags: php

I would like to write some PHP code to parse some HTML to return the href and title of all of the images in the "image_url" a class.  I am currently using substr to find the location of the strings, however the webpage sometimes changes content and I can't always rely on substr.  Is there a DOM way or some other regular expression way I can find these elements within my HTML?

```
<a class="image_url" href="/123.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="/123.jpg" border="0" title="Some dynamic length image title that is making this difficult for me"></a>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php

Comment: 2. http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Followings can give you a better idea.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001328/php-regex-to-get-string-inside-href-tag http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13882627/how-to-get-a-url-from-html-code-block http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8156913/php-regex-html-extract-url Hope it helps..

Comment: Something like `$sreg = '|<a[^>]*href="([^"]*)"[^<]+<img[^>]*title="([^"]*)"|i'; preg_match_all($sreg, $sText, $a);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 3 things as far as I know

1. php [simple xml parsing](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.simplexml.php)
2. php [domDoucment.](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)
3. [Simplehtmldom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) parser

Answer (score 0):

You can try below sample code.

```
$html='<a class="image_url" href="/123.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="/123.jpg" border="0" title="Some dynamic length image title that is making this difficult for me"></a>';   
 $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($html);

    $elements = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
    foreach ($elements as $child) {
        echo $child->nodeValue;
    }
```